# Find perimeter of right $\triangle ABC$, given segments defined on sides by bisectors

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

> Given: $\triangle ABC$ is right at $A$. $BD$ and $CE$ bisect angles $\angle ABC$ and $\angle ACB$, respectively. $AE=8$ and $AD=9$
>
> Find: perimeter of $\triangle ABC$

[image]

My solution: with the notation $x=BE$, $y=CD$, and $c=BC$,  using the bisector theorem twice leads to:

$$\frac{9+y}{c}=\frac{8}{x} \ \ (1)$$
$$\frac{8+x}{c}=\frac{9}{y} \ \ (2)$$

Using pitagoras,

$$c^2=(9+y)^2+(8+x)^2 \ \ (3)$$

Then, solving the system with equations (1), (2), (3) in the unknowns $x$, $y$ and $c$. The asked perimeter will be $P=x+y+17+c$.

Question: is there another easier way to approach the problem, avoiding solving this system involving non-linear terms? Other solutions are welcomed! and sorry if this is a dup.

Comment: 1), 2) are not correct. It should be $\frac {AD}{AB} = \frac {DC}{BC}$ and $\frac {AE}{AC} = \frac {EB}{EC}$  or similar.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The incenter $I$ has to lie on the angle bisector of $\widehat{EAF}$ and on the locus of points $P$ such that $\widehat{EPF}=135^\circ$, which is the circumcircle of $EGF$ in the following diagram ($EG\parallel AF$):
[image]

In particular it is straightforward to locate $I$ with straightedge and compass. Then $B$ and $C$ are given by $FI\cap AE$ and $EI\cap FA$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let 
$|AB|=c$,
$|AC|=b$,
$|BC|=a$,
$|AE|=u=8$
$|AD|=v=9$.

\begin{align}
b&=u\cot\gamma
,\\
c&=v\cot\beta
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
|OA|&=|OB|=|OC|=R
\\
&=\frac{b}{2\sin2\beta}
=\frac{c}{2\sin2\gamma}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\frac{u\cot\gamma}{2\sin2\beta} 
&=
\frac{v\cot\beta}{2\sin2\gamma}
,\\
\frac{u\cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma\sin\beta\cos\beta} 
&=
\frac{v\cos\beta}{\sin\beta\sin\gamma\cos\gamma}
,\\
\frac{\cos^2\beta}{\cos^2\gamma}
&=\frac{u}v
,\\
\frac{\cos2\beta+1}{\cos2\gamma+1}
&=\frac{u}v
,\\
\frac{\cos2\beta+1}{\sin2\beta+1}
&=\frac{u}v
.
\end{align}

Using identities

\begin{align} 
\cos2\beta &= 
\frac{1-\tan^2\beta}{1+\tan^2\beta}
,\\
\sin2\beta &= 
\frac{2\tan\beta}{1+\tan^2\beta}
,
\end{align}

after simplification we arrive at

\begin{align} 
\frac{2}{(1+\tan\beta)^2}
&=\frac{u}v
,\\
\tan\beta&=
\sqrt{\frac{2v}u}
-1
=
\frac{\sqrt{2uv}-u}u
,\\
\cot\gamma&=
\cot(45^\circ-\beta)
=\frac{1+\tan\beta}{1-\tan\beta}
\\
\cot\gamma
&=\frac{\sqrt{2uv}}{2u-\sqrt{2uv}}
.
\end{align}

Now we can find the sides

\begin{align} 
b&=u\cot\gamma
=\frac{u\sqrt{2uv}}{2u-\sqrt{2uv}}
,\\
c&=v\cot\beta=
\frac{uv}{\sqrt{2uv}-u}
.
\end{align}

For $u=8,v=9$ we have 
\begin{align}
b&=24
,\\ 
c&=18
,\\
a&=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}=30
\end{align}

and the perimeter of $\triangle ABC$

\begin{align}
p&=a+b+c=72
.
\end{align}

**Edit**

Expression for the perimeter can be simplified to

\begin{align} 
p&=\frac{2uv}{3\sqrt{2uv}-2(u+v)}
.
\end{align}